# Bitbake Server does not start on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am following the [Quick Start Guide for Yocto Project](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.2/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html) on **Windows Subsystem for Linux**.

I cloned all the necessary stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib \
 build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect \
 xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping libsdl1.2-dev xterm
```

cloned the repository to a directory in the `/mnt/c/Users/<myUser>/Yocto` directory

created a branch as mentioned in the manual

```
 cd poky/ && git checkout tags/yocto_2.4.2 -b poky_2.4.2
```

and executed the file

```
 source oe-init-build-env
```

Once I execute `bitbake core-image-sato` I get the following Error:

```
Previous bitbake instance shutting down?, waiting to retry...
Previous bitbake instance shutting down?, waiting to retry...                                                 
NOTE: Retrying server connection... (Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                     
File "/mnt/c/Users/<user>/Yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/main.py", 
line 441, in setup_bitbake                                          
server = bb.server.process.BitBakeServer(lock, sockname, configuration, featureset)
File "/mnt/c/Users/<user>/Yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/server/process.py", 
line 385, in __init__                                                                                                      
self.sock.bind(os.path.basename(sockname)) 
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted 
                                                                                                                                               )                                                                                                                                                                                                         
WARNING: /mnt/c/Users/des/Development/Yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/main.py:476:
 ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=14, 
family=AddressFamily.AF_UNIX, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>            
logger.info("Retrying server connection... (%s)" % traceback.format_exc())                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
NOTE: Reconnecting to bitbake server...                                                                                                                                                                   
NOTE: Retrying server connection...                                                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: Unable to connect to bitbake server, or start one
```

I stumbled upon some GitHub Issue from the WSL Issue Tracker that this might have something to do with `inotify`.

I can't figure out what is wrong here and which socket is the error really about?

Comment: Did you get any further on this? Tried the same with the same result ;-)

Comment: I think it wont work. You can use docker with windows and pull a docker image for yocto. WSL is not meant to be used for Yocto

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, I am guessing you have the path of your bitbake not in the root linux filesystem.  I edited the file main.py inside the bitbake lib directory line ~ 436 to change to sockpath = "/tmp/bitbake.sock" and got over this.  The next thing you have to look forward to is the fact that bitbake does not like case insensitive filestystems.

Comment: In dunfell, it was 'sockname'

Answer (score 1):

First of all, good for you trying out Yocto on the Windows Subsystem for Linux! You are a brave individual.

The problem you are running into is probably filesystem related.

The socket is trying to create is `bitbake.sock` referenced in `lib/bb/main.py`. This is pretty much the first thing bitbake does, so if it cannot bind to that socket the server won't start.

I should mention that you probably saw a warning that you were not using a "supported distribution". Still, it is interesting seeing someone try this idea out.

For serious development I'd recommend using virtualization until WSL is mature enough to support applications as complex as bitbake.

If you are interested in contributing to the Yocto Project and getting bitbake working on any platform check out the [newcomers page](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Newcomers), submit a feature request in the [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/), and join us for the [monthly technical call](https://www.yoctoproject.org/monthly-technical-call/). The project is always interested in using new and exciting technologies, and patches are always welcomed.

Comment: but [this WSL Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1291) says that someone is also using yocto on WSL. And I am not the [only one](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/search?p=1&q=yocto&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: Sure, plenty of people are trying, but no one currently supports it. Is your goal to support Yocto on WSL or just do a build and be done? If you want to help support WSL that is awesome. If you just want to do a build I'd recommend virtualization.

Comment: I thought of giving it a try. I have a _powerful_ laptop and wanted to give it a spin with WSL and Yocto. But How can I contribute towards WSL and Yocto together?

Comment: See my post for contributing. There have been efforts to get docker working (CROPS), but I do not believe any team has stepped up to get WSL working yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried this and had the same issue when building from within the /mnt/c/../poky/build location. As of Win ver. 1803 Build#17134.1 I can't seem to get pyinotify and the bitbake scripts to work from the widows directory.

However bitbake works from WSL when inside the WSL directory structure, when did this I simply

`cp -a -r /mnt/c/linux/. ~/`

But this was a mistake as I had already attempted to compile and had just copied my symbolic links to a new location.

I have added mc ([Midnight Commander](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwie6Nj9jtfeAhWPG3wKHf4gBF4QFjAAegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmidnight-commander.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw3ylNsUqoYeqj5lTBbm43aW)) to my WSL because I am too lazy to type everything every time and use mcedit as my default editor, because it has syntax highlighting, mouse, go to line, search support and more (but the point is get used to the terminal editor of your choice) .  My first run completed with errors, because of the fore mentioned copy path error, but after double checking the log and resetting my links I will compile again (more to come).

```
 ### Shell environment set up for builds. ###

You can now run 'bitbake <target>'

Common targets are:
    core-image-minimal
    core-image-sato
    meta-toolchain
    meta-ide-support

You can also run generated qemu images with a command like 'runqemu qemux86'
~/poky/build $ (wsl-test-yocto-2.5) bitbake core-image-sato
Parsing recipes: 100% |##################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:26
Parsing of 814 .bb files complete (0 cached, 814 parsed). 1282 targets, 46 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.37.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-16.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "i586-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "qemux86"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.5"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "m32 i586"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta
meta-poky
meta-yocto-bsp       = "wsl-test-yocto-2.5:da3625c52e1ab8985fba4fc3d133edf92142f182"

NOTE: Fetching uninative binary shim from http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/uninative/1.9/x86_64-nativesdk-libc.tar.bz2;sha256sum=c26622a1f27dbf5b25de986b11584b5c5b2f322d9eb367f705a744f58a5561ec
WARNING: The Linux kernel on your build host was not configured to provide process I/O statistics. (CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING is not set)
Initialising tasks: 100% |###############################################################################################| Time: 0:00:05
Checking sstate mirror object availability: 100% |#######################################################################| Time: 0:01:00
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
Currently  6 running tasks (1111 of 2266)  48% |##########################################                                             |
0: nettle-3.4-r0 do_populate_lic_setscene (pid 8617) 100% |####################################################################| 1012K/s
1: mpfr-native-3.1.5-r0 do_populate_lic_setscene (pid 8614) 100% |##############################################################| 970K/s
2: grep-3.1-r0 do_populate_lic_setscene (pid 8637) 100% |######################################################################| 1.54M/s
```

Comment: So mean to say that `cp -a -r /mnt/c/linux. ~/` before I download Poky should do the trick?

Comment: No, I wouldn't recommend that at all. Also not sure what you would be copying if you haven't downloaded poky yet. I was saying that running bitbake from within WSL seems to work if you are inside your Linux directory. This means that you won't be able to edit using windows apps.  I would stick with cloning into pocky from your home (~/) directory using 'git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky'

Comment: **Update,** wanted to add that  I was eventually able to get the demo/ tutorial poky bitbake to compile, after struggling with permission issues [see this wsl issues list on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=+Errno+13+) and [python manual page about os paths](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html). The **bake took 9 hours!!**   --> I **love** what the wsl team is doing and think it is incredible, but (baring a complete failure of setup on my end) it doesn't seem ready for Linux production tasks. The build on the same machine (in Linux dual boot) 47 minutes!